# Applying multiple conditional statements for new column with QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, point, fields-attributes, conditional

I have an attribute table of a point layer where each point has a `"StopID"` (range 0-37115):

[image: excerpt of attribute table]

**My goal is to create a new column in the table for a subset of 188 points where that subset is numbered from 1 to 188**. For example, if my subset is (4,0,2,1) then the column I would like to add to the excerpt of my attribute table will look like this:

[image: example attribute table]

Now I know that I could use this conditional statement:

```
case
when "StopID" = 4 then 1
when "StopID" = 0 then 2
when "StopID" = 2 then 3
when "StopID" = 1 then 4
end
```

But using that for 188 entries is very tedious and I'm sure there must be a faster way to do this. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried using `@row_number` on the exported selection, or searched for `auto increment ID`?

Comment: Your subset is a random combination of points, is not it ? What is the logic behind subset numbering, any ordering field available ?

Comment: What is the logic of your subset? Why should 4 become 1, 0-2, 2-3, 1-4 ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this expression, based on the function [`array_prioritize()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-prioritize) which allows sorting an array using the ordering specified in another array:

```
with_variable (
    'subset',
    array(4,0,2,1),  -- your subset definition
case 
when  array_contains(@subset, "StopID")
then 
    array_find( 
    array_prioritize( 
        array_agg("StopID"),
        @subset
    ),
    "StopID"
)
end
)+1  -- add 1 to start the new values at 1 instead of 0
```

[image]

Comment: Wie immer erstaunlich!

Comment: Great, thanks, that's it! Just need to increment by 1 now to start the new values at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Just add `+1` at the end of the expression. Will update the answer accordingly.